# Binary Encoding + Transport security (WCF)

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm a newb to WCF bindings and would greatly appreciate if someone could give me an example of a custom binding using Binary message encoding with Transport security (clientCredentialType="None").

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
            CustomBinding endpointBinding = new CustomBinding();
            endpointBinding.Elements.Add(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement());
            endpointBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
```